# Controller executing before factory injection complete?

Tags: angularjs

This is a two part question:

I have an empty div on my page

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="SLR" ng-controller="userMenuController">
           //Angular inject HTML here
    </div>
</div>
```

It's my understanding that ng-Controller causes the following function to execute:

```
app.controller('userMenuController', ['$scope', function($scope, authFactory){

    $scope.init = function(authFactory) {

        var menu = authFactory.getLoginModuleHtml()($scope);

        $("#SLR").html(menu);

    };

    $scope.init();
```

My First problem is even though authFactory is injected as a dependency to the controller that it is still undefined and therefore my init() function fails.  Why is this? Here is my factory:

```
app.factory('authFactory', function(){

   var factory = {};

   factory.getLoginModuleHtml = function(){

        var html = '';

        if(userLoggedIn){

            html =
                '<div class="row-fluid" ng-controller="loginMenuController">' +
                '<div class="dropdown">' +
                'Hi user!' +
                '</div>';
        } else {
            html =
                '<div class="row-fluid" ng-controller="loginMenuController">' +
                '<div class="dropdown">' +
                'Click to login!' +
                '</div>';
        }

        return html
    }

    return factory;
});
```

My second question is, am I event putting HTML on the page in the correct manner?

Thank for help.

Comment: It is undefned because of this `$scope.init = function(authFactory) {`. and you are invoking it as `init()` Remove authFactory from the function argument and it should be fine. factory is already injected into the service which is available in the upperscope, you do not need to pass it in. Also you need to specify it in the dependency as well `['$scope', 'authFactory', function...` Next use templates/views for your html as far as possible rather than constructing it in the factory

Comment: You are not using angular correctly. You should be putting your html in the template and conditionally rendering it via ng-if's, ng-shows, or ng-hides. You should not have to use jQuery in your controller as it is meant to be only used sparingly (in directives)

Comment: @PSL, you're right I was not passing authFactory in as a dependency entirely.. This solved issue.

Comment: @Conqueror I believe you may be right, but I'm already using EJS with node as my server side templating solution and express.js for my router.. I'm really only looking to use Angular for data binding and other magic, but it sounds like I should look into your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First answer:

You are not injecting your factory properly, it should be like this:

```
app.controller('userMenuController', ['$scope','authFactory', function($scope, authFactory){

    $scope.init = function(authFactory) {

        var menu = authFactory.getLoginModuleHtml()($scope);

        $("#SLR").html(menu);

    };

    $scope.init();
}]);
```

And for the second, the answer is **No**, you should never handle html tags from your controllers, always use directives for that matter.

In your case, your html is changing if the user is logged or not logged, I would recommend using a route based solution for that, so you can redirect your user to a login route whenever it is necessary, and only allow the user to see the other pages when he/she is properly logged.

Comment: templates are being rendered server-side with EJS and express.js.. BUT my authentication system is asynchronous so I need a way to update my views after the user logs in.  Do I really need to setup angular routing to solve this?

Comment: not at all, it was just a suggestion, in your case you can store the user state (logged or not) in a factory/service and bind to that value using ng-show, actually, there are many ways to solve this, but the main principle is to not handle the html tags from the controllers.

Comment: You nailed it... that's what I'm doing right meow.  Thanks everyone!